# what is the difference between those 2 Post methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

am a bit confused about the difference between this 2 lines:

```
req.OpenReadStream();
```

and

```
Request.Form.Files.GetFile("FileContent").OpenReadStream()
```

here is what i know so far and correct me if am wrong, i know that they are both meant to read a file, and the first method accept file only, however the second accept file and a json value,, 
but what i still dont understand is the difference in term of syntax

Here is a snippet from the post methods:

```
public IActionResult Post(IFormFile req)
{
    req.OpenReadStream();
    return Ok();
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] RequestModel req)
{
    Request.Form.Files.GetFile("FileContent").OpenReadStream()
    return Ok();
}

//....
public class RequestModel
{
    public string FileContent { get; set; }
    public string SomeRandomString { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. They both belong to [`IFormFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

The only difference is how you're accessing the interface.

In your first example you're accessing it directly as it's passed into the constructor of your method.

In your second example you're accessing it from the [`Files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection.files?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormCollection_Files) collection of the [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.1) by getting the file using [`GetFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection.getfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFileCollection_GetFile_System_String_) method that returns the said interface.

As Panagiotis Kanavos said, the later can not be tested at all.

Comment: Thanks man, and if i may ask, which one is better in terms of performance or best practice ?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing - performance ways - it's obviously faster to directly access the object rather than doing `GetFile` on a `Collection`. But that's not always possible depending on the scenario like yours. I wouldn't worry too much about this overhead, as I said it's minimal.

Comment: @Gru the second one can't be tested at all. It's not only about performance.

Comment: @Gru the methods *are* different. The first one posts only the file to the `Post` action. The second tries to post more data along with the file through the `RequestModel` object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think we're talking about two different things here. The OP didn't ask about his methods on the controller but about the difference in how he accesses the `OpenReadStream()` method. What you said is true, but what you said in your second comment - OP already knows about it as per his statement in the question.

Comment: @Adriani6 even so, there's an important difference

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, as I said what you said is true and valid for this matter. However this wouldn't answer OPs question.